# How can I get 2 target values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

so I am currently writing a program that can make predictions of longitude and latitude values. So far, my program can make predictions for 1 target value, but I need it to make 2. How should I go about doing that.

```
column_names = ['longitude', 'Latitude']
raw_dataset = pd.read_csv('loglat.csv', names=column_names)
dataset = raw_dataset.copy()
dataset.tail()
```

```
train_dataset = dataset.sample(random_state=0)
test_dataset = dataset.drop(train_dataset.index)
```

```
train_labels = train_dataset.pop('longitude')
test_labels = test_dataset.pop('longitude')
```

```
normed_train_data = train_dataset
normed_test_data = test_dataset
```

```
def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

  model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
  return model
```

```
model = build_model()

linreg = model.fit(
  normed_train_data, train_labels,
  epochs=1000, verbose=0)
```

```
test_predictions = model.predict(normed_test_data).flatten()
```

Right now I only get longitude predictions, but I want both.
Thank you, ~Sir Cappery

Comment: use `layers.Dense(2)`?

Comment: xdurch0 thank you for the answer, I tried it and I get an error when fitting. Saying "ValueError: A target array with shape (1, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 2) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output."

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Model API instead of Sequential API.

```
from tf.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tf.keras.models import Model


def build_model():
    X = Input(shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())])
    hidden_1 = Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu)(X)
    hidden_2 = Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu)(hidden_1)
    out_1 = Dense(1)(hidden_2)
    out_2 = Dense(1)(hidden_2)

    model = Model(inputs=[X], outputs=[out_1, out_2])
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                  optimizer=optimizer,
                  metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
    return model
```

if you need different losses for different output or etc. please check [here](https://keras.io/models/model/)

Comment: meowongac what version of tensorflow are you using?  Because it gives me an error when ever I try to import. And I tried some other conversion methods, but it still gave me the same error. Thanks.

Comment: meowongac thank you for the response, but what tensorflow modules do you have installed. I tried it and I got an error saying "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'" I am on tensorflow 2.0 beta 1

Comment: Thanks, "ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[130.4998]])]" I get this now I used the same fit

Comment: Is there any way to fix this

Comment: I don't know how your data look like. Anyway, you need to match the shape of `normed_train_data` with `shape` of `Input` layer. Let's say your `normed_train_data` have shape of `(num_data, num_feature)`, then the `shape` in `Input` layer should be `(num_feature)`. Be noticed that you don't need to specify `num_data` (number of trainset) @SirCappery